# Not able to close the application in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and java.I have created 9 activities(screens) and each one has a next button to navigate to next screen and 9th screen has an exit button to close the application.but if i call finish() or android.os.process.killProcess api's it is going to the previous screen but its not closing the whole application.

Could you please provide me the code snippet to close the whole application.

Comment: Android's design is not favoring exiting an application by choice, but rather manages it by the OS. You can bring up the Home application by it's corresponding Intent:                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);          startActivity(intent);

Comment: You can also implement this from your AndroidManifest.xml file, just adding android:noHistory="true" attribute in those <activity> you don't want to go back previous activities.

Comment: For this You can Use this code in Your Exit onClick() 

moveTaskToBack(true); but when You start again the application at that time the last activity is displayed on the screen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to come back to your previous Activities then `finish()` every Activity before starting the new Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Second option is to use `startActivityForResult()` in every Activity and `setResult()` in the last Activity that performs a call back `onActivityResult()` to all the previous Activities to `finish()`.

```
int AnyNumber = 123;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, AnyNumber);
```

override `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == MyRequestCode){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Do this in every Activity and in the 9th Activity set the Result,

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

This will call back and all the Activities will finish depending on the `requestCode`.

Comment: this is not better way or we can say that this is not exact sollution

Answer (score 0):

in main Activity:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: This is not recommended, as it can leave Android in an uncertain state.

Answer (score 0):

Use one activity and add fragments to it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html